# Trying to replicate activities from other app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can someone help me, i need to create two activities the have the same format as the ones I'm providing below, can someone help me with this? are there libraries that can assist me with this? What can of viewgroups should i use? What is the general structure, thank you (Taken from Money Lover)

Also about the second one, tried to replicate it as recyclerview, my main concern is subtypes are very well done and I can't do the same, the dotted lines and how they form in middle and as the last item, how I can show a slice of the subtypes and only show all upon request.

EDIT: The first interface also has this "Add more details" button, is it just a textview with onclick that shows the rest or is there a way better?

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use a relative layout as the parent view for both of the screens.

For the top activity the view hierarchy could look something like the below in sudo xml.

```
relative Layout>
  relativeLayout| id: "moneyRelativeLayout" marginTop: 100dp>
    imageView OR textView| id: "moneyImage" marginLeft: 50dp>
  relativeLayout: layoutBelow: "moneyRelatieLayout">
    imageView: id: "parkingImage"| marginLeft: 20dp>
    editText: id: "parkingFeeEditText"| layout_toRightOf:"parkingImage"
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

The idea is to use the properties layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf, layout_alignRight, etc to position relative layouts and their contents dynamically around the screen.

Hope this helps.